# Нарушение параллелизма Update затронула 0 из ожидаемых 1 записей

Tags: c#, sqlite

Вот обработка Update

```
 public override Quarter Update(Quarter entity)
    {
        int updateResult = 0;
        DataRow rowForUpdate = Table.Select($"{nameof(entity.Id)} = '{entity.Id}'").FirstOrDefault();

        rowForUpdate[nameof(entity.Id)] = entity.Id;
        rowForUpdate[nameof(entity.Address)] = entity.Address;
        rowForUpdate[nameof(entity.Area)] = entity.Area;
        rowForUpdate[nameof(entity.QuantityRooms)] = entity.QuantityRooms;
        rowForUpdate[nameof(entity.Price)] = entity.Price;
        rowForUpdate[nameof(entity.SellerId)] = entity.SellerId;

        //Table.AcceptChanges();
        updateResult = _adapter.Update(Table);

        if (updateResult > 0)
        {
            Refresh();
            entity = (Quarter)Table.Select($"{nameof(entity.Id)} = '{entity.Id}'", $"{nameof(entity.Id)} desc", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows).FirstOrDefault();
        }


        return entity;
    }
```

Тблц. Quarter связана с Customer по Id, все нормально, только тут почему то отображает текст, вместо ID
[image: Тблц. Quarter связана с Customer по Id, все нормально, только тут почему то отображает текст, вместо ID]

Ошибка на строке :

```
updateResult = _adapter.Update(Table);
```

Скриншот ошибки :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В чем вопрос то?

Comment: как исправить, тк. ошибка получается при обновлении

Comment: что исправить? Какая ошибка? С каким сообщением/стектрейсом? Какая конкретно строчка кода её вызывает? Вы кинули просто портянку кода и скриншот. Без пояснений это никто даже смотреть не будет.

Comment: добавил подбробно

Comment: поставьте брейкпойнт на `rowForUpdate[nameof(entity.SellerId)]=entity.SellerId;`

посмотрите что приходит в entity.SellerId.

Comment: баг был в бд, подправил уже, спасибо.